# Clarification on statement of a decomposition for graded ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

[image]

Above is a decomposition of an element $f \in R$ for $R$ a graded ring. I am confused by the statement $f_j = 0$ for $j.$ Did Professor Eisenbud mean for all but finitely many $j$ as would be the case for infinite direct sums?

[image]

More context.

Comment: What book/document is this from? That bit "*and $f_j=0\;\;$ for $j$;*" is at least written funny. Is $j$ made out to be special in the surrounding text? In general it's hard to help you and answer this question without more context.

Comment: This is from Eisenbud's 'Commutative Algebra with a view towards Algebraic Geometry'. Ill edit to add more context

Comment: I can't imagine what else that should be besides "*... and $f_j = 0$ for all by finitely many $j$;*" That is a usual part of the definition of a graded ring, after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a typo, and it should read

> ... and $f_j=0$ for all but finitely many $j$;